# how to update spinner dynamical and populate it with resourse String Array

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my application there are two spinners. The content of second spinner depends upon first spinner. So, I want to fill the second one from resource R.array.

```
if(state.getSelectedItemPosition()==2)
{
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>     (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,R.array.Panjab);
    city.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: post some relevant code here.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
             this, R.array.Punjab, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);` try this